# Odd Error in Metadata Script

Tags: python, metadata, error-000582

So I developed a script that traverses through a root directory, and any subdirectories and catalogs layers files. Then exports these layer files' FGDC metadata and outputs them to a folder. The code at this point is hit/miss sometimes completes and sometimes processes "most" of the input and errors out close to being done.

Can anyone point out what's going on here? Error code is:

> File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\conversion.py", line 624, in
>   ExportMetadata raise e
>
> ExecuteError: ERROR 000582: Error occurred during execution.

```
import arcpy,os  
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput=True  
metadataout=r'C:\tmp\out'  
for dirpath,dirnames,filenames in arcpy.da.Walk(r'C:\folder\files',datatype="Layer"):  
    for filename in filenames:  
        print filename  
        translator = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\Metadata\Translator\ARCGIS2FGDC.xml'  
        arcpy.ExportMetadata_conversion(os.path.join(dirpath,filename),translator,os.path.join(metadataout,str(filename).split(".")[0]+'.xml'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The python code for the ESRI Metadata Translator instead of the export command seemed to solve the issue.

Comment: Somehow this answer automatically got downvoted by the "Community" bot because it is so short. I apologize for that.